# Output ACF field dynamicaly within a taxonomy loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

So I have this block that loops over my taxonomies and loads a template file to display each one of them while in it:

```
<?php
  $collections = get_terms( 'resource-collection', array(
    'orderby'     => 'name',
    'hide_empty'  => 0,
    'pad_counts'  => true,
) ); ?>

<?php if ( ! empty( $collections ) ) : ?>
  <?php foreach ( $collections as $collection ) : ?>
    <?php include locate_template( 'sections/collection-tile.php' ); ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

That template file (collection-tile.php) refers to how each taxonomy is displayed on the front-end.

I´d like to output a custom field built with ACF dinamically for each taxonomy returned in the loop. It´s an image field and it´s set to return the object array. So here´s what I did in the template file:

```
<?php $img = get_field('my_custom_field'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $img['url'] ?>">
```

This should´ve done the trick. But somehow it went wrong and I get:

```
<img src= (unknown)>
```

So, it seems like WP is not able to properly address the field with the corresponding queried term in the loop.

I´ve done some research but couldn´t figure out what the problem is.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, apparently, after referring to one of ACF´s docs [see it here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/) it requires an additional argument to work with taxonomies.  Like so: **<?php $term = get_queried_object(); ?>** then using **$term** as a second parameter within **get_field()**. But still, the problem persists...

Comment: Wow! A downvote without any further feedback... that´s really helpful! By hovering over the downvote arrow, this is the tooltip: _"This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful."_ None of which are true. Go figure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, problem solved. Turned out to be a pretty basic mistake, actually.

All I needed to do was to pass on the queried term as a second parameter in `get_field();`. I even posted a comment here referencing one of ACF´s docs that explains just that...

Turns out I ALREADY had created the taxonomy array `$collections`, which would then return the correct term in `<?php foreach ( $collections as $collection ) : ?>`.

And there I was trying to do `$term = get_queried_object();` followed by `get_field('my_custom_field', $term)` in the template file. No wonder it wasn´t working... (Guess that´s the side effect of working for too many hours way into the night... you start getting dumb).

So, here it is. That´s all there is to it:

```
<?php $img = get_field('my_custom_field', $collection); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $img['url'] ?>">
```

Bam! Now it obviously works.
Nothing like a fresh day, with a fresh mind.